# PHP method for replacing BBCode quotes

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I need to replace BBCode quotes from a phpBB3 forum using PHP. Quoted posts look like this:

```
[quote=&quot;John Doe&quot;:2sxn61wz][quote=&quot;Bob&quot;:2sxn61wz]Some text from Bob[/quote:2sxn61wz]Some text from John Doe[/quote:2sxn61wz]Some more text
```

I would like to parse this string and end up with an array like:

```
Array (

    [0] => Array (

        [0] => 'John Doe' 
        [1] => 'Some text from John Doe'
    )

    [1] => Array (

        [0] => 'Bob' 
        [1] => 'Some text from Bob'
    )
)
```

What would be the best approach to recursively find these quote blocks and their content? Thanks in advance for any help on that!

**As suggested in the comments:**

```
$str = '[quote=&quot;John Doe&quot;:2sxn61wz][quote=&quot;Bob&quot;:2sxn61wz]Some text from Bob[/quote:2sxn61wz]Some text from John Doe[/quote:2sxn61wz]Some more text';
$uid = '2sxn61wz';

print_r(quoteParser($str, $uid));

function quoteParser($str, $uid) {

    $pattern = "#\[quote(?:=&quot;(.*?)&quot;)?:$uid\]((?!\[quote(?:=&quot;.*?&quot;)?:$uid\]).)?#ise";

    echo "Unparsed string: " . $str . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Pattern: " . $pattern . "<br /><br />";

    preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

    return $matches;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [quote="John Doe":2sxn61wz] [1] => [quote="Bob":2sxn61wz]S ) [1] => Array ( [0] => John Doe [1] => Bob ) [2] => Array ( [0] => [1] => S ) )
```

That's quite what I need but I don't get the quoted text. Only the user names. Any help? Thanks so far.

Comment: I would take a look about how your BBCode parser does the transformation to HTML and then take out the bits you need to create your array.

Comment: You mean the parser used in phpBB3?

Comment: Yep, this line appears to have what you need to get you started: https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/develop/phpBB/includes/bbcode.php#L195

Comment: Please see my update in the question.

Comment: Have you looked at the BBCode parser in PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: @Andy Lester I tried the HTML_BBCodeParser2 but 1) it doesn't handle the quotes in this format and 2) It doesn't seem easy to modify the library for it to output the quotes in a custom HTML fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently what you're wanting is to turn your BBCode output into HTML. You can check the [**`bbcode_create()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php) function if you like. Otherwise a different recursion -to format your text- is a better option, I believe.

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        font-size:.9em;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .post {
        margin:1em;
        padding:1em;
        font-size:1em;
        border:1px solid #999;
    }
    .post > .text {margin:1em .4em}
    .post > div:first-child {margin-top:0}
    .post > div:last-child {margin-bottom:0}

    .post > .quote {border-color:#CCC}
    .quote {
        margin:1em 2em;
        background-color:#F9F9F9;
        border:1px solid #AAA;
        font-style:italic;
    }
    .quote .text {margin:.7em 1em}
    .quote .author {
        color:#039;
        font-size:.8em;
        background-color:#E0E0E0;
        padding:.5em .8em;
        margin:.5em;
    }
    .author a {
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:inherit;
    }
    .author a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}

</style>
```

---

```
function str2html($str,$className='post') {
    $patPost =
    '~(
        \[quote=&quot;(?:(?!&quot;).)+&quot;:(\w+)(?:\])
            (?:
                (?(?=\[quote=&quot;(?:(?!&quot;).+)&quot;:\w+\])
                    (?R)
                    |
                    (?(?!\[/quote:\2\]).)
                )*
            )
        \[/quote:\2\]
    )~xis';
    // note that these 2 are not identical
    $patQuote =
    '~
        (\[quote=&quot;((?:(?!&quot;).)+)&quot;:(\w+)(?:\]))
            (
                (?(?=\[quote=&quot;(?:(?!&quot;).+)&quot;:\w+\])
                    (?R)
                    |
                    (?(?!\[/quote:\3\]).)
                )*
            )
        (\[/quote:\3\])
    ~xis';

    $arr = preg_split($patPost,$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($arr as &$value) $value = trim($value);
    unset($value);
    //echo '<h2>split post</h2>'; print_r($arr);

    $res = empty($className) ? '' : "<div class=\"{$className}\">";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 3) {
        if (!empty($arr[$i]))
            $res .= '<div class="text">' . $arr[$i] . '</div>';
        if (!empty($arr[$i+1]))
            $res .= preg_replace_callback($patQuote,'replaceQuote',$arr[$i+1]);
    }
    $res .= empty($className) ? '' : '</div>';
    return $res;
}
function replaceQuote($m) {
    //echo '<h2>replacing quotes</h2>'; print_r($m);
    $res = '<div class="quote">';
    $res .= '<div class="author">';
    $res .= '<a href="">' . $m[2] . '</a> wrote:';
    $res .= '</div>';
    $res .= str2html($m[4],'');
    $res .= '</div>';
    return $res;
}
```

You can call this by `echo str2html('some string here')`. You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot @inhan for your kind help. Unfortunately, I can't get your script to work. It seems it never enters the replaceQuote function. Trying to debug...

Comment: There must be an issue in `$patPost` but I can't tell where.

Comment: @MrUpsidown If you can post an example string or a link to it I can tell you what's going on and tweak the pattern(s) accordingly. With all the strings I tried it worked the way it should so at the moment I'm curious about what's going on with your string.

Comment: My bad... I was using a string with `"` instead of `&quot;` that works like a charm! Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @MrUpsidown Ironic. For readability I started building the pattern to match the quote characters (instead of `&quot;`) and then I changed them back before posting here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive version. It matches all the quotes in the string. This is how I would do it. If the whole purpose is to display each code better in html, then instead of matching these I would modify the contents with a proper Regex pattern instead.

```
$str =  '[quote=&quot;John Doe&quot;:2sxn61wz]' .
        '[quote=&quot;Bob&quot;:2sxn61wz]' .
        'Some text from Bob[/quote:2sxn61wz]' .
        'Some text from John Doe[/quote:2sxn61wz]' . 
        'Some more text';
$str .= '[quote=&quot;MrUpsidown&quot;:2sxn61wz]Some other quote[/quote:2sxn61wz]';
//$str .= '[quote=&quot;MrUpsidown&quot;:2sxn61wz]Yet another one[/quote:2sxn61wz]';

$pat =
'~
    \[quote=&quot;((?:(?!&quot;).)+)&quot;:(\w+)(?:\])
        (
            (?(?=\[quote=&quot;(?:(?!&quot;).+)&quot;:\w+\])
                (?R)
                |
                (?(?!\[/quote:\2\]).)
            )*
        )
    \[/quote:\2\]
~xis';

preg_match_all($pat,$str,$matches);
echo '<h2>Matches:</h2>'; print_r($matches);

$quotes = array();

function replaceQuote($m) {
    global $curArr; global $pat;
    $curArr[] = array(
        'name'  => $m[1],
        'quote' => preg_replace_callback(
            $pat,'replaceQuote',$m[3]
        )
    );
    return preg_replace($pat,'',$m[0]);
}

if (!empty($matches[0])) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $k => $v) {
        $quotes[] = array(
            array(
                'name'  => $matches[1][$k],
                'quote' => $matches[3][$k]
            )
        );
        $curArr = &$quotes[count($quotes)-1];
        $curArr[0]['quote'] = preg_replace_callback(
            $pat,'replaceQuote',$curArr[0]['quote']
        );
    }
    unset($curArr);
}

echo '<h2>Result:</h2>'; print_r($quotes);
```

And here's the output.

> ### Matches:
>
> ```
>   Array
>         (
>             [0] => Array
>                 (
>                     [0] => [quote="John Doe":2sxn61wz][quote="Bob":2sxn61wz]Some text from Bob[/quote:2sxn61wz]Some text from John Doe[/quote:2sxn61wz]
>                     [1] => [quote="MrUpsidown":2sxn61wz]Some other quote[/quote:2sxn61wz]
>                 )
>
>             [1] => Array
>                 (
>                     [0] => John Doe
>                     [1] => MrUpsidown
>                 )
>
>             [2] => Array
>                 (
>                     [0] => 2sxn61wz
>                     [1] => 2sxn61wz
>                 )
>
>             [3] => Array
>                 (
>                     [0] => [quote="Bob":2sxn61wz]Some text from Bob[/quote:2sxn61wz]Some text from John Doe
>                     [1] => Some other quote
>                 )
>
>         )
> ```
>
> ### Result:
>
> ```
>   Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => John Doe
>                         [quote] => Some text from John Doe
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Bob
>                         [quote] => Some text from Bob
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [1] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => MrUpsidown
>                         [quote] => Some other quote
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>     )
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try that out tomorrow.

Comment: That's a huge improvement! From your example, how would I also retrieve the "Some more text" and any other text that would be either before the first [quote] and after the last [/quote] ?

Comment: @MrUpsidown How would you interpret text in `txt1[quote]quote1[/quote]txt2[quote]quote1[/quote]txt3`?

Comment: text 1 [quote][quote] quote 1 [/quote] quote 2 [/quote] text 2 [quote] quote 3 [/quote] text 3 --- Basically I need to replace these quotes by some HTML tags in the string. Not sure this is the best approach though.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Why haven't you considered replacing each quote with appropriate tags, something like '<div class="quote"></div>' and write some rigid css rules?

Comment: Maybe because I was too eager to learn some regex :) But I will need a similar technique for replacing the occurences, while keeping the quoted username and the quoted text, right?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Don't worry, that will still need regex. See my other answer on how I'm using it. Uncomment the commented lines in the code to see what `preg_split()` and `preg_replace_callback()` are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$str = '[quote="John Doe":2sxn61wz][quote="Bob":2sxn61wz]Some text from Bob[/quote:2sxn61wz]Some text from John Doe[/quote:2sxn61wz]Some more text';

$quotes=array();

$quotes[]=quoteParser($str,$quotes);
print_r($quotes);

function quoteParser($str,&$quotes) {

    $pattern = "/\[quote(?:=&quot;(.*?)&quot;)?:.{8}?\](.*)\[\/quote:2sxn61wz\](.*)/ise";

    echo "Unparsed string: " . $str . "&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;";
        echo "Pattern: " . $pattern . "&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
        if(empty($matches[0][0]))
        return false;

    $var=quoteParser($matches[2][0],$quotes);
        $quotes[]=array($matches[1][0],$var?$var:$matches[2][0]);
    return $matches[3][0];
    }
```

output:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => Some text from Bob ) [1] => Array ( [0] => John Doe [1] => Some text from John Doe ) [2] => Some more text )